# How to rebuild the gpg web of trust when all keys are expired?

Tags: debian, encryption, gnupg, openpgp

Long story short, one of my machines hasn't been updated for a while, and the gpg keys it has for key servers and apt repositories have all expired. If possible, I would like to restore them to a usable state securely, without simply telling it to use an unverified key.

I have access to other machines that are properly updated, so I should theoretically be able to use one of them to get the necessary keys; however, despite much Googling and consternation, I have not been able to figure out how to do this.

The machine in question runs Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got another Debian machine you trust which has a current keyset, export them all and import them in your new machine.

On your up to date machine, run

```
gpg -a --export >keyring.asc
```

On the old machine, do

```
gpg --import <keyring.asc
```

This will add all public keys with their web of trust to the old computer.

If you trust the (SSL encrypted) Debian website, you could also download the [key archive](https://ftp-master.debian.org/keys.html) from there and import the keys.

Comment: When I did the import, gpg spat out the mysterious warning "no ultimately trusted keys found", but it seems to be working now despite that.

Comment: It turns out that Debian also has the [key archive available over SSL](https://ftp-master.debian.org/keys.html).

Comment: Good point, didn't expect that the package page wasn't encrypted. Updates to the key archive page which is more convenient anyway.